# Read out of office from exchange server for other users

Tags: asp.net, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, jdeveloper

Is it possible to pull out of office information for different users (not the current user) from MS Exchange 2010 SP2 by consuming EWS through jDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, OOF on/off is just a property on the mailbox store.

Assuming you are using the Outlook Object Model, you can access the PR_OOF_STATE MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B`) using Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

Comment: Will this property would be set at the Exchange server level or on each account?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - the property is set on each mailbox. You can see it in OutlookSpy (click IMsgStore button).

Comment: Basically i want to pull ooo info programmatically of different users. Not sure whether this would help to pull this info for other users or not.

Comment: Where is your code running? Are you using Outlook Object Model or EWS?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to access OOF settings through EWS - use GetUserOofSettingsRequest request.

Comment: I am using a java program to consume the webservice but while consuming the service it is asking for user name and password repeatedly. Any idea what authentication mechanism is it expecting NTLM or kerberos? Do you have any working sample code?